# Cross-cluster message passing in Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir, message-passing

Suppose I have two clusters like the following:

```
Cluster 1
a <---> b

Cluster 2
c <---> d
```

where `a/b` and `c/d` are separate clusters.

Now suppose I wanted to pass a message from node `a` in cluster 1 to some remote pid in cluster 2, that may be running on either node `c` or node `d`. WITHOUT joining the two clusters together, is it possible to pass messages between them with the standard Erlang/Elixir remote-communication tools, or would I need to use an external system such as RabbitMQ, Redis pub/sub, ...?

Comment: When you say "WITHOUT joining the two clusters together", do you mean avoiding a full mesh of connected Erlang nodes? Or do you mean not using Erlang distribution at all?

Comment: @juan.facorro I mean avoiding a full mesh of connected Erlang nodes